# Cut off 3d plane when it is outside a structure (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

This is all in 3d space.

I have a shape defined by a point cloud. I have also created a surface structure (faces and vertices) that MATLAB can display.

I am now trying to draw planes through the shape (see picture below). The plane is defined as normal to the midpoint between point i and i+1 on the top line. My big picture goal is to find all the points on/near each plane (say with distance < x).

[image]

But first I want to visualise all these planes to check for overlap within the shape but I'm not sure how to restrict the plane to being within (or at least close to) the shape. I'm guessing I have to define it in meshgrid but I can't find any clues online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One basic idea is to simply throw away those points of the plane you are plotting, that are not within the convex hull of your data points. You would set the values of these points in your plot to `NaN`, as this will prevent them from being shown.

I couldn't find a builtin function to check if a point is inside a convex hull.  So your options are:

- Roll your own `isInsideHull`
- Use [`inhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10226-inhull)  from the fileexchange
- Abuse the builtin [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html)

### How to abuse `scatteredInterpolant`

```
%% Your points and plane
% Random points
P = rand(400, 3);
% Random Plane
[X,Y] = ndgrid(linspace(-0.25, 1.25, 100));
Z = 3*X + 0.3*Y - 2;

%% Compute functions that are the x/y/z-identity inside the hull and `NaN` outside.
hull = unique(convhull(P)); % To make the call of scatteredInterpolant more efficient
insideHull = @(dim) scatteredInterpolant(P(hull,1), P(hull,2), P(hull,3), ...
                                         P(hull,dim), 'linear', 'none');
[insideHx, insideHy, insideHz] = deal(insideHull(1), insideHull(2), insideHull(3));

%% Plot the data points P
plot3(P(:,1), P(:,2), P(:,3), 'x');
hold on;

%% Plot the points of the plane, that are inside the convex hull of P
surf(insideHx(X,Y,Z), insideHy(X,Y,Z), insideHz(X,Y,Z));
```

So instead of the whole plane, you will just get the facets, that are within the convex hull.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

### Other approaches:

You could also try one of the following:

- [geom3d](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24484-geom3d) from the fileexchange

Comment: Thanks - that is very useful as a starting point. But my problem is that the shape loops back on itself (imagine a C shape). So I believe this method will collect points on the 'top' and 'bottom' of the 'C' if the plane goes through both sides. That is why I'm trying to cut the plane using the shape boundary. Does that make sense?

Comment: Using the boundary would be preferable, because we could have cleaner cuts, but it would still yield both the top and bottom parts and therefore would suffer from the same problem!

Comment: The planes are defined by lines which run throughout the shape. So there are lines defining the top of the C as well as lines defining the bottom of the C. So if we could cut the planes as they leave the shape, we would have different planes at the top and bottom so could find nearest points on each. Right?

Comment: Yes. But that workaround wouldn't be any easier to program than the corresponding workaround of my approach. We could use blob-detection with my proposed algorithm and select the blob, that is closest to your desired point on the boundary.